# List slicing start and end

Tags: python

```
string = "ABCDEFGH"
```

Can anyone explain why in `string[start:end:stride]`  the start always starts from `0` while end starts with `1`.

For example
`string[0:3:1]` outputs the result as `"ABC"`. As you can see I said `end = 3` so shouldn't the `string[0:3:1]` be `"ABCD"` because computer read `0` first?

And one more thing why: I don't get a result for 
`string[0:8:-1]`. Shouldn't it be `"HGFEDCBA"`? I don't know if it is wrong `syntax` or not but I can `print` the result of `string[::-1]`.

Comment: Because `start` is included and `end` is not included.  This way, `end - start` will give you the length of the slice.  When you have a `list` of length `n`, `list[n]` is out of range, the last element will be `list[n-1]`

Comment: Thank you all now it make sence.

Answer (score 0):

Since `len(string)=8`, the slice `string[0:8]` is interpreted as "all memory indices 0-7" (i.e. 8 total indices). The last index in python is "up to but not including".

For the second part of your question, the syntax is `string[7::-1]`. `string[0:8:-1]` starts at 0 and tries to increment "backward", but since it has already reached "0" at the beginning of the iteration, no traversal occurs.